# Optimization of product of standard normal CDFs.

Tags: optimization

I want to maximize $\phi(c_{1},c_{2}) = \Phi(c_{1})\Phi(c_{2})$ given $c_{1}+c_{2} = 1$, where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF of standard normal distribution and $0\leq c_{i}\leq 1$ for $i=1,2$. I did it using simulations and found the solution at $c_{1} = c_{2}$. Is there any way to solve it analytically?

Comment: I think that rewriting your expression as $\phi(c)$ = $\Phi(c)\Phi(1-c)$ would be a good place to start. Then probably differentiating. Interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not rigorous at all, but I think the intuition is the following. When you differentiate and set equal to 0, you get $$ \frac{\phi(c)}{\Phi(c)} = \frac{\phi(1-c)}{\Phi(1-c)} $$
Then, seems there are two possibilities:

- c = 1-c
- $ \frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)} = z $, with $z$ being some constant

Since the second one does not hold, seems like the first one is the right answer.